# Limit the characters of td tag in html table

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net mvc for my application. I use html table to list all the Roles from Roles table.
I have a html table which shows details of roles. The table has RoleDescription which can grow to many characters. I need to limit the characters shown in the td to 25 characters for the RoleDesscription in the tds of the html table. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static string Truncate(this string input, int maxLength)
{
    if (input.Length > maxLength)
    {
        input = input.Substring(0, maxLength - 3) + "...";
    }

     return input;
}
```

**Razor usage**

```
<td>@Model.RoleDescription.Truncate(25)</td>
```

**WebForms usage**

```
<td><%= Model.RoleDescription.Truncate(25) %></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if( someString.Length > 25 )
       someString = someString.SubString( 0, 25 )
```